# parse_url replacing the plus sign with a space

Tags: php, parse-url

```
$url = parse_url('https://plus.google.com/+erikedgren');
$address = ltrim(rtrim($url['path'], '/'), '/');
echo $address;
```

`$address` outputs `plus.google.com/ erikedgren`. Why? And how can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**

The code above outputs `+erikedgren`. But when I replace the address in `$url` with `$_GET['u']` (from `parse_url(https://plu...)` to `parse_url($_GET['u'])`), I get `plus.google.com/ erikedgren`. Let me explain how my system works.

When I click on a link on my website on my local server (I haven't released the update yet), the URL for extern addresses looks like this: `http://192.168.1.135/erik-edgren/url/https://plus.google.com/+erikedgren`.

The last part with the extern address, is what `$_GET['u']` is fetching. Here's how the RewriteRule looks like for it: `RewriteRule ^url/(.*)$    get-url.php?u=$ 1` (no spaces between $ and 1).

Comment: Copied your exact code, `$address` outputs "+erikedgren" as expected without the `plus.google.com` part. Unable to reproduce the problem. Please provide more information.

Comment: @mistermartin That was really weird. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated question, this appears to work for me:

```
$url = parse_url($_GET['u']);
$address = trim(rawurldecode(urlencode($url['path'])), '/');
echo $address;
```

I also replaced `ltrim` and `rtrim`, since `trim` will remove from both the beginning and end.

Answer (score 0):

URL encode `https://plus.google.com/+erikedgren` before including it at the end of your URL. + is a space if it is not url encoded.

Comment: Thank you but now I get the `Object not found` error. The URL is now `http://192.168.1.135/erik-edgren/url/https%3A%2F%2Fplus.google.com%2F%2Berikedgren`. If I click on another link that are not URL encoded, it works just fine.